# Появление кнопки приложения когда в буфер скопирован текст

Tags: android

Появление кнопки приложения когда в буфер скопирован текст.
Можете рассказать что это и если можно как это реализовать. Буду рад даже ссылкам на сторонние ресурсы.

[image: Вот пример такого действа от google translate]

Comment: Это кнопка - новая функция приложения Google Переводчик. Какой-нибудь сервис мониторит буфер обмена и при появлении содержимого выводит кнопку

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Возможно, есть более элегантное решение этой задачи, но если нет времени или лень искать, можно сделать так:

```
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    checkClipboard();
}

private void checkClipboard() {
    ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);

    String pasteData = "";

    if (clipboard.getPrimaryClipDescription().hasMimeType(MIMETYPE_TEXT_PLAIN)) {
        ClipData.Item item = clipboard.getPrimaryClip().getItemAt(0);
        pasteData = item.getText();
    }

    if (pasteData.equals("")) showButton();
    else hideButton();
}

private void showButton() {
    // показать кнопку, если она еще не показана
}
private void hideButton() {
    // скрыть кнопку, если она на еще не скрыта
}
```